# sendMessage: CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 ON AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

Node Code

```
// send message to aws sqs
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({
    apiVersion: '2012-11-05',
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    credentials: new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials(
        {
            disableAssumeRole: false,
        },
    ),
});

const sendMessage = async (queueUrl, message) => {
    console.log('region:', process.env.AWS_REGION, 'accessKeyId:',
        process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 'secretAccessKey:',
        process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 'AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE',
        process.env.AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE, 'AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG',
        process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG, 'AWS_PROFILE', process.env.AWS_PROFILE,
        'AWS_CONFIG_FILE', process.env.AWS_CONFIG_FILE);
    console.log(`sendMessage: ${queueUrl}, message: ${message}`);
    const params = {
        MessageBody: message,
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
    };
    await sqs.sendMessage(params).promise().then(
        (data) => {
            console.log(`sendMessage: ${data}`);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(`sendMessage: ${err}`);
        },
    );
};

const deleteMessage = async (queueUrl, receiptHandle) => {
    const params = {
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        ReceiptHandle: receiptHandle,
    };
    await sqs.deleteMessage(params).promise().then(
        (data) => {
            console.log(`deleteMessage: ${data}`);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(`deleteMessage: ${err}`);
        },
    );
};

module.exports = {
    sendMessage,
    deleteMessage,
};
```

The same code is working fine in one lambda, but in another I am getting
`sendMessage: CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

Things I have tried:

1. tried setting AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 didn't work
2. tried unsetting above: didn't work
3. tried printing the assess key and secret key they are getting printed, but not working
4. I have tried all things in this link https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1955
5. Checked all permissions but it's not permission related issue otherwise I would have got access error,
6. tried upgrading and downgrading aws-sdk version as well.

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

With AWS Lambda, you don't have to worry about the access key and secret. Simply grant the necessary rights to the Lambda's IAM role, and instantiate your SDK with

```js
const sqs = new AWS.SQS();
```

The SDK will pick up the credentials automatically.

If you want to make sure the SDK uses a specific API version, keep the `apiVersion` prop:

```js
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({
    apiVersion: '2012-11-05',
});
```

Don't log the access key and secret, that's a security risk.

To read more about the role that Lambda assumes, check the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html).

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to use inline credentials. As a better practice remove all credentials (access_key, secret_key, credentials profile etc) probably you will get access exception.
Grant the lambda SendMessage (sqs:SendMessage) permissions and you are good to go.

Answer (score -2):

you have to try this way. if you want to send message then add one key which is message in params

```
const params = {
  AttributeNames: [
    'SentTimestamp',
  ],
  MaxNumberOfMessages: 5,
  MessageAttributeNames: [
    'All',
  ],
  VisibilityTimeout: 15,
  WaitTimeSeconds: 10,
  QueueUrl":"your URL"
};

const sqsconfig = new AWS.Config({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    region:  s3AccessRegion,
    sessionToken: sessionToken,
  });
  sqs.config = sqsconfig;

//here write a function to send-receive or delete message
```